# Not able to install Microsoft update (hotfix) - msu through PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, hotfix

I am trying to install  MSU through below PowerShell script, but its not getting installed. I am not aware of PowerShell scripting. Please someone give me best way to modified this script. I am looking forward to hear.

```
Start-Process "C:\Installer\windows10.0-kb4520062-x64_9f2a827f11f945d19bd26de6f113f611a38bb8a1.msu" -ArgumentList "/quiet /norestart"
```

Comment: how do you know it's not working? you're using the `/quiet` argument which is probably suppressing any prompts or dialogue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to pass *arguments* to a process launched via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process), the (possibly positionally implied) `-FilePath` argument must be a true *executable*, not just a *document*, which is what a `.msu` file is.

Therefore, you must pass the executable that `.msu` files are registered to be processed by *explicitly* to `-FilePath`, which is `wusa.exe` (note the `/quiet /norestart` at the end of the `-ArgumentList` argument):

```bash
Start-Process `
  -FilePath     "$env:SystemRoot\System32\wusa.exe" `
  -ArgumentList 'C:\Installer\windows10.0-kb4520062-x64_9f2a827f11f945d19bd26de6f113f611a38bb8a1.msu /quiet /norestart'
```

Note:

- In order to wait for the installation to finish, add the `-Wait` switch.
- To additionally check the process' exit code in order to determine whether the installation succeeded, add the `-PassThru` switch, capture the resulting process-info object in a variable, and then check its `.ExitCode` property.

However, there is a trick that simplifies the above: pipe the `wusa.exe` call to `Write-Output`, which forces it to execute synchronously (as a GUI-subsystem application, `wusa.exe` would otherwise run asynchronously) and also records its exit code in the automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable:

```
# Note the "| Write-Output" at the end of the line,
# which makes wusa.exe run synchronously and records its process
# exit code in $LASTEXITCODE.
& "$env:SystemRoot\System32\wusa.exe" C:\Installer\windows10.0-kb4520062-x64_9f2a827f11f945d19bd26de6f113f611a38bb8a1.msu /quiet /norestart | Write-Output

if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
  throw "wusa.exe indicates failure; exit code was: $LASTEXITCODE"
}

'Installation succeeded.'
```